# Complex Z-Index stacking issue

Tags: css, wordpress, z-index

I have been trying to resolve the z-index issue with a slider on a wordpress page 
https://yamahajaipur.com/slider-test-jas/

If we mouseover to the last (+) icon, there is div that shows up. Half part of the div is not showing up due to z index stacking. I am not able to figure out the problem . I have checked the parent elements too if they have lower z-index.

As in the screenshot below , i want the selected div to be on the top of the stack(highest z-index)
[image]

Comment: Sorry about that . I have updated the question with a screenshot of what i am trying to resolve.
Appreciate if you can help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of `overflow: hidden;` declarations that are cutting off that content.  one was on the `div#n2-ss-9 .n2-ss-slider-3` element, the other was on `div#n2-ss-9 .n2-ss-slide, div#n2-ss-9 .n2-ss-canvas`.  Make those `overflow: visible` and you are probably there, but I'm not sure how that will affect other elements on the page.